# Using CanvasTexture with a Sprite

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am upgrading some code that used to work with `three.js r61` to `three.js r74`. I know, it's a big jump, but things are not always as they should be.

One of the remaining things that I still didn't get to work properly is a texture built using a canvas, used in a `SpriteMaterial` which is then used for a `THREE.Sprite`.

So far, I did the following:

- Changed `Texture` to `CanvasTexture`
- In `SpriteMaterial`, commented out the usage of `useScreenCoordinates`, `alignment` and `sizeAttenuation`

I tried various stuff, but it seems like this thing just doesn't display at all. Is there any such example anywhere? I just want to display an artifact that is built in a canvas.

**Update:** the code below is what I tried so far:

```
var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
loader.load(canvas.toDataURL(), function(texture) {
  var material = new THREE.SpriteMaterial({
    map: texture,
    blending: THREE.AdditiveBlending,
    color: me.color,
    opacity: me.opacity,
    transparent: me.transparent,
    visible: me.visible
  });

  var sprite = new THREE.Sprite(material);
  scene.add(sprite);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're quite light on details but here's one good way to do it:

https://jsfiddle.net/_jered/xcej4ec6/

```
var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
loader.load(canvas.toDataURL(), function(d){
    // 'd' is the loaded texture
    // apply it to the object here
});
```

Basically, just use the built in Loader classes to load the assets you need, including from canvas. It's important to use Loaders and callbacks because assets will become ready asynchronously, and you need to wait until they're done before you make use of them. In my example, I create the mesh with a placeholder texture, and apply it in the Loader's callback.

Comment: I added some code. If you get a chance, please take a look and let me know your thoughts.

Comment: @Dan it's the same principle with sprite materials: https://jsfiddle.net/_jered/g31m188L/ There is also a SpriteCanvasMaterial you could try, it's in the documentation.